# AVR linker scripts: why start data memory at 0x60?

Tags: linker, ld, avr, atmega, linker-scripts

I don't have much experience with linker scripts, so maybe I'm just misunderstanding something here. The LD linker script for the ATmega32u4 (avr5.x) specifies that data memory (SRAM) starts at `0x800060`. I know that `0x800000` is just a special offset that the compiler uses for SRAM pointers, but why use `0x60` as the base of RAM? The ATmega32u4 datasheet shows that `0x60` is the start of external I/O registers and that SRAM actually starts at `0x100`. Doesn't that mean the external I/O registers will be clobbered when the `.data` section is copied into SRAM?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is something GCC accounts for if you invoke `avr-ld` through it. GCC overrides the virtual address of the `.data` section depending on what you passed to `-mmcu=`. If you link with `avr-ld` directly, the `.data` section is at the default `0x800060`.